# Antl4 no rule index for labelled rules

Tags: antlr4

For the grammar snippet from Java.g4,

```
statement
    :   block                                             # blockStmt
    |   'if' parExpression statement ('else' statement)?  # ifStmt
    |   'for' '(' forControl ')' statement                # forStmt
    |   'while' parExpression statement                   # whileStmt
    ;
```

All the alternatives are labelled.
I can get all StatementContext objects using this method

Trees.getAllRuleNodes(root,JavaParser.Rule_statement);

But if I am only interested in getting the IfStmtContext objects, how can I use the above method without using something like this

```
for(ParseTree tree : statementContextList)
{
if(tree instanceof IfStmtContext)
{
//add to a list
}
```

The generated JavaParser doesnt create rule indexes for labelled rules. 
Do I have to customize the grammar in some way to make them indexed? 
Or there is another ways do this?

My code should be fast and I need to remove as much as iterations and conditions as possible. Need to get rid of the 'instanceof'  checks as well as possible

Comment: I'm pretty sure `instanceof` is **not** the bottleneck in your code. Have you actually profiled it? You're optimizing the wrong thing, the parsing pass is *much* more expensive.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I thought using so many 'instance of ' considered to be not a good practice.  In my case, I don't have to care for the parsing speed. What I am looking is ,   after the parsing and getting the ParseTree object, how can I process the data in an optimized way. I think the Antlr framework uses the Rule_Index string matching which i felt better than  'instanceof' . So if there a way to create Rule_Indexes for the labelled rules also, I can do much more.